# ListView android looses background color

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an adapter which extends ArrayAdapter> filling fragment layout with multiple choices each time.
The problem is that sometimes background disappears completely on items choose before, or all other items. If you check this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5IMZ.png

you can see that ccc option lost background. Layout inflates this Relative Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selectable_background_example"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >
```

With this background xml

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused_example" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_background_example" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_background_example" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_background_example" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/new_strip"/>
</selector>
```

Pressed_background_example

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@color/pressed_example" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/pressed_example" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

</shape>
```

Pressed_example

```
<resources>
    <color name="pressed_example">#CCCC0000</color>
</resources>
```

And new_strip is basically just that background white image with border, and list_focused_example is image for checkbox pressed.

GetView in my class

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder mhHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        mhHolder = new Holder();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_a, parent, false);
        mhHolder.txtValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtValue);
        mhHolder.txtCheckbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        mhHolder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtText);
        convertView.setTag(mhHolder);
    } else {
        mhHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    HashMap<String, String> hm = values.get(position);

    mhHolder.txtValue.setText(hm.get("Value"));
    mhHolder.txtText.setText(hm.get("Text"));
    mhHolder.txtCheckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //TODO CHANGE WHEN CHECKED IS SEND      
    mhHolder.txtCheckbox.setChecked(Base.checked[position]);
}
```

Does anyone have any clue on why the background dissapears on previous selected items or sometimes on all items except the selected one.

Comment: Can you post list_focused_example and new_strip code?

Comment: Hi! As said this are only images. new_strip is the background image you can see around every field (white background with gray round borders, this basically disappears). And list_focused_xample is just a pressed checkbox image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was the image (new_strip). I had to make a drawable the same as the image (which had only white background and gray rounded corners), so that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it´s a kind of bug (or I don't really get the real function).

Anyhow you should try to call

```
mhHolder.txtValue.setbackground(R.drawable.selectable_background_example);
```

in your code so that it is executed for each item.

Comment: Nope doesn't fix it. Addit to txtValue just adds background to the EditText child and then I have 2 backgrounds and the problem still appears. Adding  backgroundResource to the convertView doesn't do anything better, still bugged. I forgot to mention that this works on mobile phone if tested but not on Tablets